# How to define values from a userform when in VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access, userform

I have the following code that runs perfectly:

```
DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO BudgetTable (Category, AccountNumber) VALUES (forms![AddScenario]![txt_ACCOUNT_CATEGORY] , forms![AddScenario]![cmb_SELECT_ACCOUNT])"
```

I am now trying to clean it up a little so I have changed it as follows:

```
Dim ScenarioAccount As String
Dim ScenarioCategory As String

ScenarioAccount = Forms![AddScenario]![cmb_SELECT_ACCOUNT]
ScenarioCategory = Forms![AddScenario]![txt_ACCOUNT_CATEGORY]

DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO BudgetTable (Category, AccountNumber) VALUES (ScenarioCategory , ScenarioAccount)"
```

I keep getting an error. Any idea where I am going wrong?

Any assistance will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Ideally you would [edit] your post to include the actual error you're getting, but `ScenarioCategory` and `ScenarioAccount` are local variables in VBA code, the SQL engine has no knowledge of them. See if square-bracketing them works some magic (I'm not familiar with Access), otherwise you might need to [concatenate the values into the command string](https://xkcd.com/327/) (e.g. `VALUES (""" & ScenarioCategory & """,""" ScenarioAccount & """)"`), or to parameterize an actual `Command` instead of using `DoCmd` ;-)

Comment: Concatenate variables. I prefer an apostrophe delimiter instead of doubling quote marks. `VALUES ('" & ScenarioCategory & "','" ScenarioAccount & "')"`. This is for text type field, date/time requires #, nothing for number. Also prefer `CurrentDb.Execute` instead of `DoCmd.RunSQL` so I don't have to deal with popup warnings or turn warnings off then on.

Comment: Thanks Mathieu, all solved